# Google Charts Ajax data reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-visualization

I'm updating google chart data using an Ajax call, but experiencing performance issues when dynamically updating chart data.

**Functionality:**

- A button is pressed to add new data to the chart
- backend script (PHP) stores new data in database
- Data in chart is reloaded

**Issue:**
When decoupling the update of the data and the reload of the chart, all works fine. But when directly reloading the chart after reloading the data the is a lag of 5 seconds before the chart renders. (not related to the Ajax call, that is done in ms)

Can you help me solve this issue?

**Javascript coupled version [SLOW]:**

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    //Some code here to update database
    $("#area").load(url, function() {
       //update the chart after ajax has been completed
       update_chart();
     }
}

function update_chart(){
    $.ajax('load_data.php')
        .done(function(data) {
            if(data){
                chart_data = JSON.parse(data);
                window.data2=data;
                drawChart();
            }
        });
} 

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(window.data2);
    var options = {
        legend:  {position: 'none'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**Javascript decoupled version [FAST]:**

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    //Some code here to update database
    $("#area").load(url, function() {
       //not updating the chart here
     }
}

//update the chart after a press of another button
 $(".reload").click(function(){
       update_chart();
  };
```

Comment: are you sure your `update_chart` function is running just once?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I checked logging every part of the function.